# How to stop a while loop with a click function?

Tags: jquery, ajax, upload

It's kind of complicated: I have a form with a file input field and an upload button below. By clicking on that upload button a Function is fired that does an ajax call to check if a file with the same name is already in the upload directory. If the file doesn't exist the "start_upload"-function is fired:

```
function start_upload(){
    while(start < SIZE) { //start and end is 0 and ~200Bytes - that's the size of the parts of the file
        i++;
        upload(blob.slice(start, end), i, name, SIZE);
        start = end;
        end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
    }
}
```

The upload function looks like this:

```
function upload(blobOrFile, part, name, size) {
    var formdata = new FormData();
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    formdata.append('blob', blobOrFile);
    formdata.append('part', part);
    formdata.append('filename', name);
    xhr.open('POST', 'upload2.php', true);
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        uploaders.pop();
        if (!uploaders.length) {
            //some code that's fired when upload has finished
        }
    };
    //some other irrelevant functions
    uploaders.push(xhr);
    xhr.send(formdata);

}
```

Everything works fine but because of usability reasons I wanted to create a cancel upload button too. I tried following:

This cancel function stops all current "POST"-Requests, but starts again from zero.

```
$("#cancel").click(function(){
    xhr.abort();
});

$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
    //do something after all ajax requests are finished or aborted
});
```

Any idea how I could abort the uploads permanently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flag value for this purpose as follows :

```
 int flag=0;
    function start_upload(){
    while(start < SIZE && flag==0) { //start and end is 0 and ~200Bytes - that's the size of the parts of the file
        i++;
        upload(blob.slice(start, end), i, name, SIZE);
        start = end;
        end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
    }
}
```

And your cancel button will be :

```
$("#cancel").click(function(){
flag=1;
```

});

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Yeah thank you! :) Well, I had to use two  #cancel click functions that it finally worked as expected but now it's all good. Two functions because one outside the function to change the global flag variable outside the upload function (using the function inside the upload function will always return 0) and the other #cancel function inside the upload function to use xhr.abort(); because outside the function xhr is undefined.